# In LibSVM, svm-scale gives data that is all 1 and -1

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

As is described in the title, when I try to use svm-scale to scale my regression data into [-1, 1], the scaled data is all 1 or -1. I've confirmed that the original data itself has no problem. I'm on Ubuntu and this is my command line.

```
./svm-scale data.out > data.out.scale
```

(data.out is my original data)

This is my original data:

> 1.1 1:43.45122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 1.0 1:43.465122 2:30.67488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 9.0 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.21951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 1.0 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.7561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 4.5 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.64952 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 3.7 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:5.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 7.8 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 2.9 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.58049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 0.2 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:5.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 13.8 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:8.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.821951
>
> 1.2 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.0878 12:30.821951
>
> 1.8 1:43.465122 2:30.670488 3:50.121951 4:35.97561 5:45.649512 6:45.041707 7:55.134878 8:44.858049 9:50.183415 10:38.410732 11:56.80878 12:30.8211

And this is the scaled data:

> 1.1 1:-1 2:-1 3:-1 4:1 5:-1 6:1 7:-1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1
>
> 1 1:1 2:1 3:-1 4:1 5:-1 6:1 7:-1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1
>
> 9 1:1 2:-1 3:1 4:1 5:-1 6:1 7:-1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1
>
> 1 1:1 2:-1 3:-1 4:-1 5:-1 6:1 7:-1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1
>
> 4.5 1:1 2:-1 3:-1 4:1 5:1 6:1 7:-1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1
>
> 3.7 1:1 2:-1 3:-1 4:1 5:-1 6:-1 7:-1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1
>
> 7.8 1:1 2:-1 3:-1 4:1 5:-1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1
>
> 2.9 1:1 2:-1 3:-1 4:1 5:-1 6:1 7:-1 8:-1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1
>
> 0.2 1:1 2:-1 3:-1 4:1 5:-1 6:1 7:-1 8:1 9:-1 10:1 11:1 12:1
>
> 13.8 1:1 2:-1 3:-1 4:1 5:-1 6:1 7:-1 8:1 9:1 10:-1 11:1 12:1
>
> 1.2 1:1 2:-1 3:-1 4:1 5:-1 6:1 7:-1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:-1 12:1
>
> 1.8 1:1 2:-1 3:-1 4:1 5:-1 6:1 7:-1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:-1

Am I wrong about the parameters or the data? Pls help. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the scaling is correct. you made up your data by multiple copies of a line and altering values in the main diagonal only. this leads to exactly two different values in each row the smaller one scaled to -1 and the bigger one scaled to 1. make more modifications to your input data and you'll see rational numbers in the scaled data.